# Universal push notification sending

Tags: android, ios, cordova, parse-platform, push-notification

I've got a server written in Scala/Java. I want to make an app in PhoneGap/Cordova which uses push notifications.
I would prefer to have one codebase for both Android and iOS. Is there a way to do universal push notifications for both Android and iOS.
Is using Parse Push REST API for that purpose a good decision, cosidering that I've already got my own server?

If it sounds opinion based, excuse me. I'm new in this topic, and just want to decrease the redundancy as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Parse, but clientside if you are using Cordova then the [PhoneGap Push Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) should be what you are looking for, it's available for iOS, Android, Windows and others and let's you handle the Push Notifications in Javascript.

I don't know how you could solve this platform independent on the server side, though.